# What is the difference between the epochs parameter used in tuner.search and max_epochs used in keras tuner?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, hyperparameters, keras-tuner

I am following this keras-tuner notebook tutorial:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1K1r62MkfcQs9hu4QCE9KRFzQRd9gXlm2?usp=sharing

And I have a doubt.

```
tuner = kt.Hyperband(model_builder,
                     objective='val_accuracy',
                     max_epochs=10,
                     factor=3)


tuner.search(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[stop_early])
```

Why do they use max_epochs smaller than epochs?
What is the difference between those parameters?
Are those epochs the same?
Or one epoch is related with fitting the model parameters and the other with the hyperparameters tuning process?

This question has already been asked but received no replies:
[keras tuner difference between max_epochs in hyperband(() and epochs in search()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76158957/keras-tuner-difference-between-max-epochs-in-hyperband-and-epochs-in-search)